# Queries from multiple databases on the same server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have information spread out across two databases and want to put some information onto one web page using PHP.

```
mysql_select_db('info',$conn);
mysql_select_db('users',$conn);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `sheet1` WHERE `mtr` = 989";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (logged_in($user_data['mtr']) === true) {

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['nr_matricol'] . " " . $row['Numele']. " " . $row['D']. " " . $row['E']. " " . $row['F']. " " . $row['G']. " " . $row['H']. " " . $row['I']. " " . $row['J']. " " . $row['K']. " " . $row['L']. " " . $row['M']. " " . $row['N']. " " . $row['O']. " " . $row['P']. " " . $row['Q']. " " . $row['R']. " " . $row['S']. " " . $row['T']. " " . $row['U']. " " . $row['V']. " " . $row['W'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
}
```

I have one field `mtr` in the first database and in the second db. How can I query those two databases to show me data only for one user (the one that's currently logged in)?

I know I have to change this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `sheet1` WHERE `mtr` = 989";`
```

but don't know how.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Thank you Jason for advice,i'm just starting so I don't know much,and thx Michal for answer,that code is working in mysql but it give me some error when i'm trying to show that data in php,i will sort that out

Answer (score 0):

Simple select from 2 databases:

```
SELECT * 
FROM database_2.table_2 
JOIN database_1.table_1 
     ON (database_2.table_2.some_field = database_1.table_1.some_other_field) 
WHERE database_1.table_1.data_1 LIKE database_2.table_2.data_2
```

Comment: I used this way also in my projects

Comment: That worked,but i still have a litle problem,it still shows all the data from my database,not just a single field for the logged in user.